# need help for prev and next button in react

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar-4

How to call back the effect operation when clicking the prev button using method or function with fullcalendar4 in react?

At present, I can only think of this way:

```
componentDidMount(){
document.querySelector('.fc-prev-button').addEventListener('click', e => {console.log(e)})
}

componentDidMount(){
document.querySelector('.fc-prev-button').addEventListener('click', e => {console.log(e)})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it works with React. Have you read some docs [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react#callbacks) about callbacks, or [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react#accessing-fullcalendars-api) specifically working with react and the underlying calendar's ref?

I've created a simple code sandbox that uses the callback style you try, and also using the API. Between the two, your method seems less recommended, but IMO is a little cleaner as it uses all the existing in-place UI, but is susceptible to being a little more brittle as the class names could potentially change, whereas using the API for next/prev these are calling methods directly so less likely to change.

[image: Edit determined-fog-78un7]

I guess it depends a lot on what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, but what you have will "piggyback" off the button click, so if you're just trying to do something on the side it'll work.